# ng-model assign value in html and read and assign in controller $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am a Angular newbie and trying to achieve this,

**Assign a ngmodel value in view and read it back in controller to pass it to my service**

```
<input name="item" ng-model="itemId"  ng-init="itemId='3'">
```

In my controller i am accessing it via

```
@MyDevelopmentApp.controller 'myCtrl',[
  '$scope'
($scope) ->
  console.log($scope.itemId)
```

It returning **undefined**.

How can i return the Id from my view to the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code in the controller is being executed before `ng-init`. If you wait until it has been parsed, it should work: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C59CW/5/)

Edit: You can register a watcher that will be triggered when the value is initialized or when you change the variable afterwards. Updated fiddle with an example.

Comment: But my other variable value is dependent on ng-init value, as it will be served to another service like `Tag.getTags($scope.itemId)`

Comment: @AnkitG you can use `$scope.$watch` to get the functionality you need, edited my answer.

Comment: @AnkitG Using ngInit the way you want to use is is not the Angular way. From the docs: `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.`

Comment: @Mosho, You solution worked, watching the Id and them assigning to a variable worked